# Visualize interval type data graphically and regression

Tags: regression, visualization

Suppose I have data like this:

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 10 |
| 10 | 12-30 |
| 15 | 45 |
| 20 | 50 |
| 25 | 55-60 |

I want to visualize it graphically. How can I do it? I googled how to describe intervals graphically, but didn't find anything. And I also want to do regression analysis on the data.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What tools are you familiar with or hoping to use?

Comment: I just googled it. Nothing else.  I want to do it (i.stack.imgur.com/UzK0M.png) on Python,but not with time series. Is it possible?

Comment: Related: [52351](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/52351/)

Answer (score 0):

You can visualize intervals using histograms. For regression, try out OLS. Or you can reframe it as a classification task.

Comment: Well, I want to do it (https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzK0M.png) on Python,but not with time series. Is it possible?